# Save Rendered Geometry of Shapes and use them in a custom shape

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, geometry, shapes

We have an application and we need a custom shape per each signal(changeable value in time) to add it in canvas for having a reference. in future by changing the signal value shape must changing to. for example if value=1 the shape must be a rectangle and if value=2 shape must be an ellipse.
I want to save Geometry of these shapes in a list and use them when I want.

I have an Idea for this case but it dosent work.

```
public class DigitalShape : Shape
{
    public Geometry SelectedGeometry
    {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue(SelectedGeometryProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedGeometryProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedGeometryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedGeometry",
        typeof(Geometry), typeof(DigitalShape), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            return SelectedGeometry;
        }
    }
}
```

Get geometries from shapes with RenderedGeometry like this:

```
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Width = 20;
        rect.Height = 20;
        rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
        rect.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
        rect.Stroke = Brushes.Yellow;
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, 100);

        DigitalShape _symbolShape = new DigitalShape();
        _symbolShape.SelectedGeometry = rect.RenderedGeometry;
```

please help me guys.

Update 1:

testing data property of path with this code in new project, but I didn't see the rectangle:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Width = 20;
        rect.Height = 20;
        rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
        rect.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
        rect.Stroke = Brushes.Yellow;
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, 100);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.Data = rect.RenderedGeometry;

        myCanvas.Children.Add(path);
    }
```

Update 2:
using path from another way. when myElp is hard coded and created in xaml, rendergeometry is worked and get a right geometry with values but when I create myElp in Code behined rendergeometry give me an empty geometry.

Xaml Code:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Width="200" Height="200" Background="Aqua"/>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,234,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="myElp" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="25" Margin="23,0,30,20" Stroke="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

Code Behined:

```
        PathGeometry pathGeo = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(myElp.RenderedGeometry);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.Data = pathGeo;

        path.Stroke = Brushes.Yellow;
        path.StrokeThickness = 1;
        path.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
        Canvas.SetLeft(path, 10);
        Canvas.SetTop(path, 10);

        myCanvas.Children.Add(path);
```

I see 2 Ellipse when Run this code. 1 its own ellipse of xaml and 1 my path.

How can i use render geometry for shape who created in code behined?!

Comment: Use a Path and set its `Data` property instead of creating your own derived shape.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it dosent work.". And provide [a good, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Clemens: Can I Set Data Property of path with renderedGeometry of a shape ?

Comment: I think so. You may perhaps need to create a copy by calling `RenderedGeometry.Clone()`.

Comment: nothing changed by using clone :(